# cannot import repo from from http://localhost/xxx/xxx.git

Tags: apache, proxy, gitlab, puma, isaserver

I am working with gitlab 5.2 setup on my localhost (http://example.com), on Centos 6.4
I am facing the following problem ,
when i try to create a new project with import existing repository and provide a github clone link (eg:https://github.com/XXXX/yyy.git) a new project is created as expected with imported repos,
but when i try to create a new project with import existing repo and provide a gitlab link(eg: `http://example.com/xxxx/foo.git`)`which is on my own machine a new **EMPTY** Project is created 
my puma.stderr.log says :

```
error: The requested URL returned error: 502 Proxy Error ( The ISA Server denied the specified Uniform Resource Locator (URL).) while accessing http://example.com/xxxx/foo.git/info/refs
```

it seems that my puma is not able to reach the requested url , or maybe the gitlab-shell is not able to access the repo (as there is no way to check the logs of gitlab-shell)

(the example.com is only localhost)

finally some hope the apache server cannot resolve localhost 
the error in the apache log is

```
[error] avahi_entry_group_add_service_strlst("localhost") failed: Invalid host name
```

my gitlab.conf is

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
       Order deny,allow
       Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:9292/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:9292/
</VirtualHost>
```

and my /etc/hosts file is

```
127.0.0.1 marvin localhost
170.xx.xx.x marvin localhost
```

also the hostname command gives

```
marvin
```

the hostname --fqdn command gives

```
marvin
```

where am i going wrong.?

also i have tried editing the 
etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost
170.95.204.18 marvin localhost
::1 localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
```

but no success..

Answer (score 0):

Add to your domain.conf path log and error log

```
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/yourdomain.log combined
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/yourdomain-error.log
```

For example:

```
root@debian:/home/marek# cat /etc/apache2/sites-available/yourdomain.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName yourdomain
  DocumentRoot "/home/marek/public_html/yourdomain/web"
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  <Directory "/home/marek/public_html/yourdomain/web">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>

  Alias /sf /home/marek/public_html/yourdomain/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf
  <Directory "/home/marek/public_html/yourdomain/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>

  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/yourdomain.log combined
  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/yourdomain-error.log

</VirtualHost>
```